# Installing VS 2012 Tools for Office 2013 - Workflow Client 1.0 Beta.problem

Tags: visual-studio, 2013

Installing my development environment, I have:

1. Virtual Machine with Windows Server 2012
2. SharePoint Server 2013
3. Visual Studio 2012

I need Visual Studio Tools for Office 2013.  Using Platform Installer, I run into problems with Workflow Client 1.0 Beta.

[image]

It seems, that Workflow Client 1.0 is already installed, and it is not Beta version.

[image]

How can I continue with installing tools in order to start developing farm solutions for SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incidentally, [Microsoft announced new version of Office Tools on 12. Nov](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/11/12/announcing-the-latest-release-of-office-developer-tools.aspx). I strongly recommend installing this version instead. This solves Workflow Client problem.